# Does the Ritual Caster Feat grant access to Subclass Spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

Ritual Caster states:

> You have learned a number of spells that you can cast as rituals. These spells are written in a ritual book, which you must have in hand while casting one of them. When you choose this feat, you acquire a ritual book holding two 1st-level spells of your choice. Choose one of the following classes: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard. You must choose your spells from that class's spell list, and the spells you choose must have the ritual tag. The class you choose also determines your spellcasting ability for these spells: Charisma for bard, sorcerer, or warlock; Wisdom for cleric or druid; or Intelligence for wizard.

Would a character be able to chose Druid and gain access to the added rituals from the Druid Subclass Grassland Circle (i.e. Divination)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No. Only the base list

The spell lists per class are in the Spells chapter; for Druid that's the list under "Druid Spells".

The spells/rituals from the Grassland Circle are added by the special feature called "Circle Spells". The only way to get that special feature is by being a level 2 Druid (and selecting it).

Circle Spells specifically says:

> If you gain access to a spell that doesn’t appear on the druid spell list, the spell is nonetheless a druid spell for you.

Since you lack this feature, these spells aren't considered druid spells for you.

Other features have the same type of wording; *having* that special feature adds those spells to the list, but you don't have that special feature, so you're stuck with only spells listed in the default list for your chosen class.